# Cómo cambiar todo lo que tengo en sympy a matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

estaba haciendo una "grafica" en sympy y necesitaba hacer lineas segmentadas onda ( - - - -) pero cuando vi no se podían hacer en sympy y en matplotlib si, y quería saber si hay alguna forma de pasar lo que ya tengo hecho en sympy a matplotlib para asi no arruinar todo lo que hice

```
x, y = symbols('x y')

# Plot implicit(And()) grafica el conjunto de solucion
p1 = plot_implicit(And(y < (40-7*x)/5, y > -(2/3), y <= 3,
                       y <= (10+x)/2), (x, -15, 16), (y, -4, 6),
                   line_color="red", xlabel="Eje X", ylabel="Eje Y", show=False, depth=4,
                   markers=[{'args': [6.19, -0.667, 'go']},  # Punto en la posicion x,y, lo ponemos en cada vertice
                            # Todo los 'go' son puntos en la posicion x,y
                            {'args': [3.571, 3, 'go']},
                            {'args': [-4, 3, 'go']},
                            {'args': [-11.333, -0.667, 'go']}],
                   annotations=[{'xy': (4.65, 1.63), 'text': "y<(40-7*x)/5", 'color': 'tab:orange'},  # Se añaden las letras en xy,texto, color respectivamente
                                {'xy': (0.3, 3.6), 'text': "y<=3",
                                 'color': 'tab:Green'},
                                {'xy': (0.3, -1.7), 'text': "y>-(2/3)",
                                 'color': 'tab:Blue'},
                                {'xy': (-10, 2), 'text': "y>-(2/3)",
                                 'color': 'tab:cyan'},
                                # Escribimos las coordenadas de cada punto en el grafico
                                {'xy': (6.73, -0.98), 'text': "(6.19,-0.667)"},
                                {'xy': (3.98, 3.14), 'text': "(3.571, 3)"},
                                {'xy': (-6, 3.14), 'text': "(-4, 3)"},
                                {'xy': (-11.7, -1.3), 'text': "(-11.33, -0.66)"}])


# Se hace cada linea en su lugar con en un grafico aparte, show=False es para que no se muestre el grafico
p2 = plot(-2/3, (y, -15, 8), show=False)
# y_var=x lo "Mueve" dej eje
p3 = plot((40-7*x)/5, y_var=x, show=False)
p4 = plot(3, (y, -15, 8), show=False)
#"El  (x, -1000, 1000) es para que se dibuje completamente, o quedara mal, por una cuestion de como funciona la libreria sympy"
p5 = plot((10+x)/2, (x, -1000, 1000), line_color="cyan", show=False)

# Se juntan todos en un grafico y se muestra todo ahi
p3[0].linestyle = 'dashed'
p2._backend.ax[0]._children[0].set_linestyle('dashed')
p1.append(p2[0])
p1.append(p3[0])
p1.append(p4[0])
p1.append(p5[0])
p1.show()
```

Comment: Asi que digamos un "traductor" de sympy a matplotlib no existe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe un traductor de codigo.